# Create a smooth plot with given maximum and minumun x values in ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, curve

I want to create a plot in ggplot showing the water level of a tidal system over a time span of several days. I have the water levels for each High and Low Tide, but when I plot them in ggplot the line looks edgy and I would like it to look curvy. I tried to use geom_smooth but that will not work. Has someone any idea?

[image: This is how it looks like]

[image]

`+---------------+-------------+
| Water.level_m |   Time_h    |
+---------------+-------------+
| 3.9           | 0           |
| 1.4           | 0.270833333 |
| 3.8           | 0.516666667 |
| 1.5           | 0.7875      |
| 3.7           | 1.041666667 |
| 1.7           | 1.308333333 |
| 3.9           | 1.5625      |
| 1.7           | 1.829166667 |
| 3.6           | 2.091666667 |
| 1.8           | 2.35        |
| 3.8           | 2.608333333 |
| 1.7           | 2.875       |
| 3.6           | 3.141666667 |
| 1.8           | 3.4         |
| 3.9           | 3.654166667 |
| 1.6           | 3.9375      |
| 3.8           | 4.191666667 |
| 1.6           | 4.454166667 |
| 4.1           | 4.704166667 |
| 1.3           | 4.9875      |
| 4.2           | 5.245833333 |
| 1.2           | 5.504166667 |
| 4.4           | 5.75        |
| 0.9           | 6.025       |
| 4.5           | 6.275       |
| 0.8           | 6.5375      |
| 4.8           | 6.7875      |
| 0.6           | 7.058333333 |
| 4.8           | 7.308333333 |
| 0.5           | 7.566666667 |
| 5             | 7.816666667 |
| 0.4           | 8.083333333 |
| 5             | 8.3375      |
| 0.2           | 8.6         |
| 5.2           | 8.85        |
| 0.2           | 9.108333333 |
| 5.1           | 9.3625      |
| 0.1           | 9.625       |
| 5.2           | 9.879166667 |
| 0.2           | 10.14166667 |
| 5.1           | 10.39166667 |
+---------------+-------------+`

Comment: Do you want to plot high and low tide as separate lines or do you want your current plot but with smooth lines?

Comment: I want the current plot with smooth lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `spline()` to interpolate your original data points:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:20,
  y = rep(c(-1, 1), 10) * 1:20
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data = as.data.frame(spline(df, n = 300, method = 'natural')), aes(x = x, y = y), color = 'red')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One possibility of smoothing the line is to make a [sigmoid curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function) between each pair of points. Since you haven't provided the data in a format that is easy to copy, let's make up some mock data as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:20,
  y = rep(c(-1, 1), 10) * 1:20
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

You could make a sigmoid curve out of this as follows:

```
sigmoid <- cbind(head(df, -1), tail(df, -1))
names(sigmoid)[3:4] <- c("xend", "yend")

sigmoid <- apply(sigmoid, 1, function(dat) {
  x <- seq(dat[["x"]], dat[["xend"]], length.out = 10)
  A <- dat[["y"]]
  K <- dat[["yend"]]
  B <- 10
  C <- 1
  mid <- mean(c(dat[["x"]], dat[["xend"]]))
  y <- A + (K - A) / (C + exp(-B * (x - mid)))
  data.frame(x = x, y = y)
})

sigmoid <- do.call(rbind, sigmoid)
```

Feel free to vary the B and C parameters to fit your data. Have a look at the linked wikipedia page above for an explanation of the parameters.

Now the plot would look like the following combined with the input data:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data = sigmoid, colour = "red")
```

[image]

In order to not misdirect people with your graph, I recommend to include the actual measurements as points on the graph.

Comment: This is a nice idea, unfortunatly i cannot fit the sigmoid curve to my parameters with the variation of B and C.